# sonarqube and RTC eclipse plugins crash

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, rtc

when i install the sonarqube eclipse plugin my RTC plugin crushes and all projects are closed. In the workspace log it says that he cannot resolve the plugins and some other errors.

Answer (score 0):

There have been reports of [errors between Sonar and RTC before](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1879?jql=text%20~%20%22rtc%22), so it will depend on:

- the version of sonarqube
- the version of RTC
- whether or not this is an Eclipse RTC IDE or a more recent Eclipse with RTC and sonarqube plugins.
- the exact error generated by the RTC

Reporting that to the [SONARIDE project](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE) is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, the work around that allows Sonar(3.4) and RTC(4.0.6) to work together is the order in which the plugins are installed.  You first need to uninstall both sonar and RTC, then install sonar first, then RTC.  This worked for me.